# Why redux is required for React Native mobile App?

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, native

I am experience developer of native android app but I am entry level developer for React Native.

I am familiar with basic but not able to understand why Redux is used with React Native?

I want understanding of Redux feature in respect to Android Native App using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is Redux**: Redux is state management provide library and its upto you that you want to use or not. but in the complex apps its recommended for use.

**Why Use**:lets understand with example- You hit a api and get users data and you need it in many screens.Then how will you manage this.

- Hit api on every screen is not a good idea it makes your app very
  slow.
- Pass data with navigation will make your navigation slow and heavy
- Local-storage will difficult to handle and make slow your app also.

**and with Redux once you store data in Redux-state you can access this data anywhere in your app until you refresh your app.**

Answer (score 2):

Redux is not "mandatory" in a React Native mobile application. It is just an optional state management library that usually been used in a medium/large React Native application.

Think Redux as a state management over the application. For example, you log in as a user called "Tom". With Redux, you can save the user data into a "store". Then when you want to use it in a profile/account page, you just need to grab the user data from your "store" and display it.

Now imagine if you don't have a Redux. When you want to grab that user data, you either need to call API from database to get the data or you need to pass the user data from login again and again until you reach the profile/account page.

In conclusion, Redux is just a tool that can help you manage your data over the application. It is not required to use Redux in a small application because it can over complicated your application. But, it is suggested to use it when you try to build a medium/large application.

Comment: if i store login data or any state data in DB or AsyncStorage then is it fine if i not use redux?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is totally fine. Redux just help you manage it better and try to make your code cleaner

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of @Thimothy, it's easy to pass the data from a parent to a child but not the inverse. Redux give the power to React and React/Native to pass the data in all the ways.

However, if the user quit and relaunch the application, you need in your logic to relaunch all the API calls to recover the data.

Good luck !

Comment: Using Redux as channel to pass data from child to parent is considered to be overkill. Instead, you can use simple callback function passed from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this post was updated, but I think Redux is now overkill for most mobile apps these days with the introduction of newer solutions like [React-Query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/). Redux has been overkill for most web apps in that it was originally meant for building a single page application that could have various states over time like a MS paint clone. Recently I've been updating an old react-native app for my day job and it uses Redux for mostly fetching data and caching it so it doesn't get fetched for multiple screens. It's pretty much a CRUD app where if you're on this screen, display this data. There is no need to have a complex state management solution in this case, but at the time Redux was the only reliable solution.

Comment: react-query is not solution of redux. both are different things. redux is really required if app is high complx

Comment: They both are meant for different situations sure, but I'm saying redux is complicated for new devs to learn, it requires a lot of boilerplate code, and it's overkill in a lot of situations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).